# Dojo how to extend a dijit class?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I need to add some custom function on  `dijit/form/Select` at the moment I use the following code but I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: SelectGroup is not a constructor

How to fix this issue ?

```
require([
  'dijit/form/Select',
  'dojo/_base/window',
  'dojo/domReady!'
], function(Select, win) {

  var SelectGroup = define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/form/Select"
  ], function(declare, Select) {
    return declare(Select, {
      myCustom: function() {
        alert('hey custom');
      }
    });
  });

  var select = new SelectGroup({
    name: 'select',
    options: [{
      label: '<i>Colors I love</i>',
      value: 'G 1',
      disabled: true
    }, {
      label: 'Red',
      value: '1'
    }, {
      label: 'Green',
      value: '2',
      selected: true
    },
    ]
  }, 'select');

  select.on('change', function(value) {
    alert(value);
  }); 

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think It was just an error from you when writing the define() inside require , (AMD imbrication calls ) !

It's Simple , You have just to make all your import(requires) including the declare , and the call declare ( to make your widget direclty ) , it'll return the new widget in your `var SelectGroup` reference

Please find below a working snippet :

```js
require([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/form/Select",
    'dojo/_base/window',
    'dojo/domReady!'
  ], function(declare, Select, win) {
  
    var SelectGroup = declare(Select, {
      myCustom: function() {
        alert('hey custom calue is = '+this.value);
      }
    });
    
    var select = new SelectGroup({
    name: 'select',
    options: [{
        label: '<i>Colors I love</i>',
        value: 'G 1',
        disabled: true
      }, {
        label: 'Red',
        value: '1'
      }, {
        label: 'Green',
        value: '2',
        selected: true
      },
    ]
  }, 'select');
    
    
    select.on('change', function(value) {
      select.myCustom();
    });

   
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />

<script>
  window.dojoConfig = {
    parseOnLoad: false,
    async: true
  };
</script>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<body class="claro">
  <div id="select"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: what is the difference between define and declare?

Comment: Yeah , we cant make comparision between declare and define :) ,
declare is a js class , that in dojo we can create , classes , widget , and aslo extend existing class or widget ,

But define is a dojo AMD loader , which load these class , widget  asynchronously , 

so you can say comparison between require , and define , not with the declare ( declare is a loaded class ) and rquire define are loaders

Comment: In dojo standart , creating a new class , you have to chose define wich creates a scope for your created widget  + load the refrenced widget into callback function ,  and for require it loads only the refrences to the claback , in your example you mixed them , require -> and inside it a define in wich I think it caused the issue .

Comment: So if you want to create the widget in diferent js file , use Define then impot it in the calling js file by require , otherwise just use only require  for all the refrences ( including decalre ) and create you widget/class .

Comment: Could you please help me out on this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413483/convert-decorator-to-custom-widget-in-dojo ??? thanks

Comment: that was Done :)